# React - Why Optional chaining is not working for this axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, optional-chaining

Im getting this error for the code below:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

I tried to use optional chaining but it's not working...

```
const [deliveredOrders, setDeliveredOrders] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getDeliveredOrders = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/api/orders`);
    setDeliveredOrders(res.data);
  };
  getDeliveredOrders();
}, []);

console.log(deliveredOrders?.delivered[0]?.updatedAt);
```

Comment: `deliveredOrders` is an array. Arrays are non-nullish, so the chain is not entered into when you do `deliveredOrders?.`. But then, it's an array, not a plain object - so it doesn't have a `delivered` property. `someArray.<somePropertyName>` is almost always a mistake unless `somePropertyName` is `length` or a whole number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you optional-chained wrong properties, it's `delivered` which is `undefined`

It should be:

```
deliveredOrders?.delivered?.[0]?.updatedAt
```